# Simulating vibration as when receiving a call

Tags: android, vibration

So I am trying to simulate that the phone is receiving a call. I have successfully extracted the phones ring tone and played it. Now I want to simulate the vibration. While I can make the phone vibrate, I want to emulate the exact pattern that the phone vibrates with as when it receives a call. Is there some setting or class that I can use to extract this pattern, and also detect if vibration is turned on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to vibrate it in a pattern.

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);  

// 1. Vibrate for 1000 milliseconds  
long milliseconds = 1000;  
v.vibrate(milliseconds);  

// 2. Vibrate in a Pattern with 500ms on, 500ms off for 5 times  
long[] pattern = { 500, 300 };  
v.vibrate(pattern, 5);
```

http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/22/

I'm not sure what pattern is used as standard, you could probably find it in the source, or else keep trying different patterns yourself until it is satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks, the first call works great. But I think the API might have changed for #2. The second parameter is an index into the pattern array, so 5 wouldn't work. You can have a look over here for a description of the method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html

Comment: I don't see where it has changed? The second parameter is an int that defines the number of times the pattern should be repeated, so 5 should be valid.

Comment: While it does not truly solve my problem, it is still the best solution available, so I'll accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no class that can provide you with 'standart' vibration settings for incoming call.
Since most phones come with custom vendor caller apps and since there are a lot of custom caller apps on Google Play, this 'standart' pattern probably doesn't even exist.

Standart caller app from AOSP uses this pattern:

```
private static final int VIBRATE_LENGTH = 1000; // ms
private static final int PAUSE_LENGTH = 1000; // ms
```

And to detect if the vibration is turned on:

```
boolean shouldVibrate() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int ringerMode = audioManager.getRingerMode();
    if (Settings.System.getInt(mContext.getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing", 0) > 0) {
        return ringerMode != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT;
    } else {
        return ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE;
    }
}
```

This relies on the "Vibrate while ringing" and "Sound mode" settings you can find in standart phone settings.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the Android source in order to see how they do it?

The Phone app source is available from
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone